# Looping through diagonal+1 of a matrix

Tags: r, matrix

I need to loop through the diagonal+1 (i.e. the values 1 column to the right of the diagonal) and write the value to a column in a dataframe:

```
write.csv(data.frame(matrix[1,2], matrix[2,3], matrix[3,4])
```

How can I do this using a function, rather than just listing all the positions of the values?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can index using a matrix.

eg

```
m <- matrix(1:25, ncol = 5)
```

The off diagonals can be accessed using

```
offd <- cbind(1:4,2:5)


m[offd]

## [1]  6 12 18 24
```

You could create a function that does this

```
offdiag <- function(m, offset){
  i <- seq_len(nrow(m)-offset)
  j <- i + offset
  m[cbind(i,j)]

}


offdiag(m, 1)
## [1]  6 12 18 24
offdiag(m, 2)
[1] 11 17 23
offdiag(m, 3)
## [1] 16 22
offdiag(m, 4)
## [1] 21
```

Comment: This is probably faster, and should work well with sparse matrices. I think your code is clearer, but this is the code in `diag` for the case where its first argument is a matrix: `y <- c(x)[1 + 0L:(m - 1L) * (dim(x)[1L] + 1)]`

Answer (score 9):

A fast way of doing this without the head-scratching of working out the indices programatically is to use the oft-overlooked `row()` and `col()` functions. These return for each element of a matrix the row or column that element belongs to respectively.

The diagonal is where the row index of an element equals the column index. The first subdiagonal is where the row index equals the column index *plus 1* whilst the first superdiagonal is where the row index equals the column index *minus 1*.

Here are some examples:

```
m <- matrix(1:25, ncol = 5)
m

> m
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]    1    6   11   16   21
[2,]    2    7   12   17   22
[3,]    3    8   13   18   23
[4,]    4    9   14   19   24
[5,]    5   10   15   20   25
```

### The diagonal

```
m[row(m) == col(m)]
diag(m)

> m[row(m) == col(m)]
[1]  1  7 13 19 25
> diag(m) ## just to show this is correct
[1]  1  7 13 19 25
```

### First subdiagonal

```
m[row(m) == col(m) + 1

> m[row(m) == col(m) + 1]
[1]  2  8 14 20
```

### First superdiagonal

```
m[row(m) == col(m) -1]

> m[row(m) == col(m) -1]
[1]  6 12 18 24
```

Higher-order super- and subdiagonals can be extracted by increasing the value added to the column index.

### Creating the data frame and writing out

Essentially you already have this, but

```
write.csv(data.frame(m[row(m) == col(m) + 1), file = "subdiag.csv")
```

### A general function for sub- or superdiagonals

```
diags <- function(m, type = c("sub", "super"), offset = 1) {
  type <- match.arg(type)
  FUN <-
  if(isTRUE(all.equal(type, "sub")))
    `+`
  else
    `-`
  m[row(m) == FUN(col(m), offset)] 
}
```

In use we have:

```
> diags(m)
[1]  2  8 14 20
> diags(m, type = "super")
[1]  6 12 18 24
> diags(m, offset = 2)
[1]  3  9 15
```

Comment: Upvoted, `cuz that's the way I wudda dun it plus its got that kewl match.arg call, but actually think @mnel's solution is better.

Comment: Thanks; would you elaborate on *why* you think @mnels' solution is better?

Comment: The use of `row` and `col` requires construction of 2 full logical matrices of the same size as the input matrix. His just builds two vectors and extracts.

Comment: Right, I see what you mean - two length `nrow(m)` vectors vs two length `prod(nrow(m), ncol(m))` vectors. So in terms of memory efficiency especially, @mnel's solution wins hands down.

Comment: This approach wins in flexibility.  The same function can select a sub- or super-diagonal, simply by changing sign of the argument.

Answer (score 6):

Take the submatrix, then the diagonal of that.

Using mnel's `m`:

```
diag(m[, -1])
[1]  6 12 18 24
```

As a function with variable offset (but in this form, it is not any cleaner than mnel's solution):

```
offdiag <- function(m, offset) {
  s <- seq(offset)
  diag(m[,-s, drop=FALSE])
}

offdiag(m, 1)
## [1]  6 12 18 24
offdiag(m, 2)
## [1] 11 17 23
offdiag(m, 3)
## [1] 16 22
offdiag(m, 4)
## [1] 21
```

Comment: +1 Good idea, though for non-square matrices `diag(m[,-1])` might be better.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien Yes, that is better.

Comment: Really elegant. Didn't know that about `diag`'s capability.