# Best way of storing 100 matrices in R?

Tags: r, matrix

I'm writing a function that generates 100 matrices. Once I have this, I need to loop through the first superdiagonal on each matrix and extract the values. These values are supposed to go into a dataframe - 1 column for each superdiagonal. Let me illustrate:

#### First Matrix (The positions labeled as X should be extracted)

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
[1,]  1    X   .2   .1
[2,] .7   .8    X   .5
[3,] .6   .9   .4    X
[4,] .5   .1   .1   .2
```

So I need to loop through 100 of these matrices, get all the positions of each matrix labeled as X (first superdiagonal) and then I need to put each first superdiagonal in a data frame like this:

#### Output dataframe

```
         matrix1 matrix2 matrix3
[1,2]    .5      .2      .1
[2,3]    .5      .1      .2
[3,4]    .3      .7      .8
```

Given this scenario, what is the best way of storing the 100 matrices that I will later access to create the **output dataframe**? Objects? A dataframe consisting of matrices?

Additionally - are there other factors besides the one that I have posted that impacts my choice of data structure?

Comment: For one thing, if in your matrix-generating function, you output all your matrices into a single list, you can then easily `sapply` over each matrix and get back a nice data frame.  Also, are all 100 matrices the same dimensions?

Comment: Yes, all the matrices are 10x10. So the list would then consist of 100 matrices, each occupying 1 position in the list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Writing from my phone, but you can try this:

```
as.data.frame(lapply(matrixList, function(M) diag(M[, -1]) ))
```

Alternatively, if they are all exactly `10x10`, you can substitute this as the 'function(M)` above

```
    M[(1:9)*11]
```

Comment: Your superdiagonal is not quite correct.  See here for several methods to get the function to apply: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15672585/looping-through-diagonal1-of-a-matrix

Comment: @MatthewLundberg, thanks for pointing that out (the second/alterante line should be correct though), and thanks Josh for the edit.